# Converting an existing angular 2 project to use angular CLI

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I have a project that was not created using `ng new` (rather, I followed the [quickstart](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html) guide). When I run an angular CLI command in that project (such as `ng generate`) I get this error message:

> You have to be inside an angular-cli project in order to use the generate command.

Is there a way I can turn my existing project into an angular-cli project? (I wanted to try using it because it apparently automatically works around [an issue with barrel imports and SystemJS](https://github.com/angular/angular.io/issues/1301).)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You should be able to run `ng init` and follow the prompts. Have a look at this issue if you need some guidance: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/755

**Edit (March 13, 2017):**

`ng-init` was removed from the latest version of the angular cli. 
https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/pull/4628

So for now you'll need to resort to mimicking what it tried to accomplish. 
ie:

1. Create a new angular project
   ng new myTemplate
2. Copy relevant files to your existing project from your new myTemplate project:

   .angular-cli.json
   package.json
   tslint.json
   src/polyfills.ts
   src/styles.css
   src/tsconfig.json

Depending on the state of your existing application you may want to copy over way more or way less. I guess this is why the feature was removed from the CLI. There isn't really any way for it to know exactly what you want it to do.

Comment: Is there an `ng-init`? Not sure.

Comment: `Copy relevant files to your existing project from your new myTemplate project:` Do you mean `Copy relevant files FROM your existing project TO your new myTemplate project:` ?

Comment: @Diego No, I mean copy the relevant files from the myTemplate project. The whole point here is to try to make your existing project in to an project powered by angular cli.

Comment: What if you're needing an angular-cli.json file for an older project? If I used the method of generating a new angular project, it would now create an angular.json file instead.

Answer (score 2):

`ng init` [has been removed](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/pull/4628). What worked for me was to manually create a `.angular-cli.json` file in the root folder with the following keys:

```
 {
    "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
    "project": {
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "name": "new-cli"
    },
    "apps": [
      {
        "root": "src",
        "outDir": "dist",
        "assets": [
          "assets"
        ],
        "index": "index.html",
        "main": "main.ts",
        "polyfills": "polyfills.ts",

        "prefix": "app",
        "scripts": [],
        "environmentSource": "environments/environment.ts"
      }
    ]
  }
```

You will have to change values according to your setup of course.

Answer (score -1):

ng init was removed from the latest version of the angular CLI but You can use **yarn package manager** to resolve all the dependencies.
In order to use **yarn**, you have to install it first.

To install yarn in Ubuntu, enter the following command in your terminal:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install yarn
```

For Windows you can download yarn installer from
[here](https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/install#windows-stable) .

After installing yarn, you can run the command **yarn install** in your project direcotry which will download all the dependencies of your project.

For additional information about yarn [check official docs](https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/usage)

Answer (score -3):

Try the below solution may be it could help.

1. Run this command on root folder `npm install -g angular-cli`
2. Create new folder for your project `ng new project_folder_name`
3. Enter inside that folder `cd project_folder_name`
4. Run the project by this command `ng serve` (Note: Now on localhost:4200, the demo project will run)
5. Copy the `src` folder of your existing project and replace with the `src` of your newly created project from **project's root folder only**.

Copy everything from package.json from the existing project. Run npm install again.If it breaks, it probably needs tinker with webpack.config

Comment: I don't think this is really an answer as blindly copying everything from that new CLI project over your existing SRC seems like a spray and pray solution.