# How to generate .angular-cli.json file in Angular Cli?

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I have installed Angular CLI package separately using npm:

```
npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@latest
```

When I try to use commands `cli` I get an error:

```
Unable to find any apps in `.angular-cli.json`.
```

How to generate `.angular-cli.json` for current project?

Comment: have you tried `ng new your_app` ? make sure you have install `@angular/cli@latest` globally as well.

Comment: I have installed project yet, I dont need new project

Comment: `.angular-cli.json` is created by `@angular/cli` automatically when you create new project from `ng new`

Comment: I have created project not using cli, and after I installed cli using npm

Comment: See this post: [Converting an existing angular 2 project to use angular CLI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38836487/converting-an-existing-angular-2-project-to-use-angular-cli)

Comment: Well, the quick fix would be to create a new app using angular cli and copy the `.angular-cli.json` to your project root!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I got this same error in my current project and was confused because I'm running the application / ng serve in one terminal, but got this when I tried to generate a component from another terminal. *.angular-cli.json* was already there and correct. So what gives?

I realized that I used the shortcut to open VisualStudio Code's internal terminal -- which opened the terminal to the *root of the **project** * (like most IDEs). The project contains other things in addition to the Angular application folder that has the .angular-cli.json file in question.  I just had to cd to the right folder and run *ng g c* again and things were fine.

In my case it was just a silly error. I thought I'd come back to share in order to save people a real headache for something so simple. I see that Shiva actually has mentioned this above, but I thought I would give a bit more detail so it doesn't get overlooked.

Answer (score 102):

In Angular 6, `.angular-cli.json` has been replaced with `angular.json`

For Angular < 6:

Create a new file with name '*.angular-cli.json*'
and add this file in your main directory.

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "project": {
    "name": "my-app"
  },
  "apps": [
    {
      "root": "src",
      "outDir": "dist",
      "assets": [
        "assets",
        "favicon.ico"
      ],
      "index": "index.html",
      "main": "main.ts",
      "polyfills": "polyfills.ts",
      "test": "test.ts",
      "tsconfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
      "testTsconfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
      "prefix": "app",
      "styles": [
        "styles.css"
      ],
      "scripts": [],
      "environmentSource": "environments/environment.ts",
      "environments": {
        "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
        "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
      }
    }
  ],
  "e2e": {
    "protractor": {
      "config": "./protractor.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "lint": [
    {
      "project": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
      "exclude": "**/node_modules/**"
    },
    {
      "project": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
      "exclude": "**/node_modules/**"
    },
    {
      "project": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json",
      "exclude": "**/node_modules/**"
    }
  ],
  "test": {
    "karma": {
      "config": "./karma.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "defaults": {
    "styleExt": "css",
    "component": {}
  }
}
```

Comment: In Angular 6, `.angular-cli.json` has been replaced with `angular.json`! Hope this helps others who came here wondering where their config file went!

Comment: @adam0101 are the contents / nodes within the file changed too. I found the angular.json file but there is no node that says "apps"? A lot of the other nodes are changed too!

Comment: When you say main directory, are you referring to the root folder? Example, {angular_project_folder}\.angular-cli.json ? Like that? 2nd question, is dot(.) necessary in the file name?

Comment: @adam0101 may I know where Can I find app in Angular.json file?

Answer (score 31):

Since Angular version 6 `.angular-cli.json` is [deprecated](https://blog.angular.io/version-6-of-angular-now-available-cc56b0efa7a4#ae92). That file was replaced by `angular.json` file which supports workspaces.

Answer (score 9):

You are just outside the directory which you are working. Enter into the directory which your project is there and run command `ng g c name`.

Answer (score 1):

I found similar error it was located to  `C:\Users\sony\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\@schematics\angular\workspace\files`

it is installed in windows try to search in c drive **angular.json** you will view the file

Comment: Can you explain that further? What should one do after viewing that specific file? How does that solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

In `angular.json` you can insert all css and js file in your template.
Other ways, you can use from Style.css in src folder for load stylesheets.

```
@import "../src/fonts/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css";
@import "../src/css/bootstrap.min.css";
@import "../src/css/now-ui-kit.css";
@import "../src/css/plugins/owl.carousel.css";
@import "../src/css/plugins/owl.theme.default.min.css";
@import "../src/css/main.css";
```

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't see .angular-cli.json too. Because my Angular version is 6. 
ng version  -> Angular CLI : 6.0.7.
Check your Angular version.

Comment: since angular 6 `angular-cli.json` is deprecated in favor of `angular.json`

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know Angular-cli file can't be created via a command like Package-lock file, If you want to create it, you have to do it manually.

1. You can type ng new  to create a new angular project
2. Locate its .angular-cli.json file
3. Copy all its content
4. Create a folder in your original project, and name it
               .angular-cli.json
5. Paste what copied from new project in newly created angular cli file of original project.
6. Locate this line in angular cli file you created, and change the name field to original project's name. You can find the project name in package.json file

> ```
> project": {
>   "name": "<name of the project>"
> },
> ```

However, in newer angular version now it uses angular.json instead of angular-cli.json.

Answer (score -1):

If you copy paste your project the .angular-cli.json you wil not find this file try to create a new file with the same name and add the code and it wil work.