# Angular Cli not generating angular-cli.json

Tags: angular, angular-cli, progressive-web-apps

I'm trying to make a new pwa and I need to write things in `angular-cli.json`.
I'm using

```
Angular CLI: 1.7.4
Node: 8.11.1
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 5.2.10.
```

After `ng new pwaapp --service worker` there's not an `angular-cli.json` file in the project folder.

Every idea is a breath of fresh air. thx

Comment: Did you check on my below answer? If you are still missing the file, post your ls from your project root along with package.json file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm wondering if you are creating Angular 6 and not Angular 5.x, as Angular 6 don't have angular-cli.json anymore. Its angular.json. See if you have this file. If you are creating a new project at this time, Angular 6 is the latest stable with some improvements to PWA as well.

[Here](https://www.djamware.com/post/5afa31a780aca726dee1fd6c/getting-started-build-angular-6-web-application) is a doc if you want to create an app first and then add PWA options after creating.

Answer (score 1):

Well to start you are not using the command correctly.

You are using `ng new pwaapp --service worker` while you should be using
`ng new pwaapp --service-worker` which should generate an `.angular-cli.json` file.

If not, then see if you @angular/cli global package is up to date.

If nothing works, add the the file yourself as referenced here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45705204/3123228

Comment: It was a typo. i'm using 'ng new pwaapp --service-worker', and still does not work. i'm gonna do it manually, and maybe it will work. thx

Comment: Yep, you were right, angular.json was the thing i was searching for

Comment: @hyena I referred to angular.json in the below answer. Wondering why it’s commented in this answer and marked as the accepted one ?? ☹️