# Problem to start project using javascript library easypz

Tags: javascript, typescript

I download this github repository https://github.com/michaschwab/superzoom, then run the command npm i, then src/environments/environment.ts. With start the project i have an error Cannot read property 'config' of null. Please, help me, what i need to do?

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR;

At the root of the project, add a file `.angular-cli.json` which contains :

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "project": {
    "name": "my-app"
  },
  "apps": [
    {
      "root": "src",
      "outDir": "dist",
      "assets": [
        "assets",
        "favicon.ico"
      ],
      "index": "index.html",
      "main": "main.ts",
      "polyfills": "polyfills.ts",
      "test": "test.ts",
      "tsconfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
      "testTsconfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
      "prefix": "app",
      "styles": [
        "styles.css"
      ],
      "scripts": [],
      "environmentSource": "environments/environment.ts",
      "environments": {
        "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
        "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
      }
    }
  ],
  "e2e": {
    "protractor": {
      "config": "./protractor.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "lint": [
    {
      "project": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
      "exclude": "**/node_modules/**"
    },
    {
      "project": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
      "exclude": "**/node_modules/**"
    },
    {
      "project": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json",
      "exclude": "**/node_modules/**"
    }
  ],
  "test": {
    "karma": {
      "config": "./karma.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "defaults": {
    "styleExt": "css",
    "component": {}
  }
}
```

---

This issue is related to angular. Why this error happens ? Check here : https://github.com/angular/quickstart/issues/525. How to resolve the issue ? Check here : [How to generate .angular-cli.json file in Angular Cli?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45207900/how-to-generate-angular-cli-json-file-in-angular-cli)