# Angular 15 showing component vertically as opposed to horizontally

Tags: css, angular

I am trying to use this code - see this link [angular stackblitz link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-ribbon-demo?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)

I am using angular 15. When I download the code and run it locally it is displayed vertically  Any ideas what I need to do to style the component horizontally. Is there a reason it is behaving differently in angular 15?

(Flex is being used for the layout)

This is a screenshot of what I am getting with the same code. It should display horizontally but no matter what changes I make to the style sheet it won't

[image]

Comment: Must be a css issue. Would be useful to see where and what you put as css for the component.

Comment: I created a scss file for the component and put exactly the same scss file contents that is in the stackblitz demo styles.scss.  When I edit this file it does change the style of the component but I can't for the life of me figure out why it will not display horizontally locally.

Comment: have you added the stylesheet to the component attribute styles array?

Answer (score 0):

You need to import styles.css to your angular.json
add `styles.css` to the `style`section. Also wanted to mention that since [angular 6](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50786293/10884884) angular-cli.json is deprecated.

Comment: I have added the src/styles.scss to the styles array like this 

"styles": [
              "@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css",
              "src/styles.scss"              
            ],

Comment: What happens if you break the viewEncasulation?

Comment: Tried the different options available (none, ShadowDom & Emulated ) but only the angular material icons are being removed. No change to it being displayed vertically. I just can't get my head around this. it should be simpler I feel

Comment: I think I finally got your problem. Do this to your component stylesheet: `:host {
    width: 100%
}`

Comment: made no difference unfortunately!

Comment: presume I would be asking a lot but if you pull the demo code locally to a local project do you get the same problem?

Answer (score 0):

Ok got it working but I had to explicitly state the class "mat-card-content" as a class attribute of  in the html.

Why do I need to set it explicitly. Has something changed in angular material that would make this a requirement? Just looking to better understand what is going on under the hood so I can avoid this kind of problem in the future.